# Is this considered a texture? and how was it added?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-editing

How were the blue stripes created in the image below?  Was this a photoshop-like texture?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways this could be done that it is hard to say.

One way would be to have an image that has the blue circle thing with the stripes on it, and just display part of the image (with masking or something similar).

Another method would be to overlay a texture with only the lines (and a proper alpha (transparency)) component, on top of a blue background.

You could also draw individual lines on top of a blue background.

Comment: If I was imitating this design, what would be the best way to make it?

Comment: I would personally go for the masking since it makes creating the texture easy (just a blue square with lines on it). Apply a second texture which is just a black texture with white where the blue is supposed to go on top, and blend the two. This would also allow you to animate the lines by wrapping and scrolling the blue/lines texture.

Comment: I would definitely use a vector mask. That was not what my question was concerned with.  I wanted to know how the lines were made on the blue. Sorry if that was not clear.